# Django pytest for login

Tags: python, django, pytest-django

Im new to pytest and was trying to test login. Im not sure how to approach for testing login

login views.py

```
@api_view(['POST','GET'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def ulogin(request):
    username = request.POST['uname']
    password = request.POST['pass']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        auth_login(request,user)
        serialized = LoginSerializer(user)
        print serialized.data
        return Response(serialized.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        print "invalid user"
        return Response( {
            'error_message':"Username/password is incorrect.",
            },status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

I tried the following code and was unable to run succesfully `error:'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'uname'`

```
 def test_ulogin(self,client):
    user = User.objects.create(uname="qw", password='qw')
    response = client.post('/', {'uname': 'qw', 'password': 'qw'})
    print response.uname
```

How should we write test case for login. Any help on this is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to testing using `pytest` library or any other library or framework you use `assert` (or similar function) to validate your assertions for pytest you can check the `assert` documentation [here](http://pytest.org/latest/assert.html).

Python also has an `assert` [statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) which can also be used to validate the assertions.

Some examples using python's assert statement:

```
assert 2 + 2 == 5 # Raises an AssertionError
assert 2 + 2 == 4 # No exception raised
```

In the first example I tried to validate the assertion that 2 + 2 is equal to 5 but we since it is not true python raises an `AssertionError`.

Second example is validated and hence no exception is raised.

Now lets come back to your problem. You want to test your login API which accepts username and password in POST parameters.

For this you can make some basic assertions such as:

- If correct username and password are provided the status code should be 200 (assert response.status_code == 200).
- If incorrect username or password is provided the status code should be 401 (assert response.status_code == 401)

You can come up with more such assertions for your `ulogin` function.
and validate using pytest's `assert` function.